# How to disable the Default sorting applied to groups in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid

```
element.kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
    data: scope.people,
    group: {
    field: "name"
    }
},
groupable: true,
sortable: false,
pageable: {
    refresh: true,
    pageSizes: true
},
columns: scope.columns
});
```

Passed Data Source 
$scope.people = [man1, man2, man3, man4]; 
    var man1 = new Man('Test name2', 25); 
    var man2 = new Man('Test name1', 28); 
    var man3 = new Man('Test name1', 21); 
    var man4 = new Man('Test name3', 21);

Actual REsult : 
Group are displaying in following order 
First Name : Test name 1 
First Name :  Test name 2 
First Name :  Test name 3

Expected Result :
**Group should display in following order** 
**First Name : Test name 2 

First Name :  Test name 1 

First Name :  Test name 3**

How do we achieve this?
By default groups are getting displayed in ascending order. But I want the order of group as it is there in the DataSource

Answer (score 2):

If you can add your data through Ajax, then it's not too hard. I haven't found a way to do it without ajax though.

Your ajax would look like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  ...[add your data call info here]...
}).done(function(result) {
  var data = result.d.results; //this may be different for others
  var sortNum = 1;
  var lastVal;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var val = data[i]["Firstname"];
    if (!lastVal) {
      lastVal = val;
    }
    if (val !== lastVal) {
      sortNum++;
      lastVal = val;
    }
    data[i]["SortOrder"] = sortNum;
  }
});
```

This is if you just want to pass the data as is into your kendo grid.
Now that you have a sort column, tell kendo to group on that new column and replace the text with the original group column to display the names correctly.

```js
//fetch FirstName value and return it to display instead of SortOrder value
function getHeader(val) {
  var $data = $('.grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();

  for (var i = 0; i < $data.length; i++) {
    if ($data[i].SortOrder === val.value) {
      return data[i].FirstName + '';
    }
  }
}

$('.grid').kendoGrid({
  //... do all your normal kendo initialization, I'll just add the stuff you need to change 
  dataSource: {
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: { //add the new SortOrder column
          SortOrder: {
            type: 'number'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    group: {
      field: "SortOrder"
    }
  },
  columns: [{ //add the new SortOrder column, but call the getHeader function to override the value displayed
    field: "SortOrder",
    hidden: true,
    groupHeaderTemplate: getHeader
  }]
});
```

That should be all you need to do. Hope this helps.